# Entity Framework code-first and Interfaces

Tags: entity-framework

Entity Framework code-first creates a single table for all objects that implement the same interface, adding a ‘discriminator’ column containing the type of object...

My boss wants to see the data in separate tables… is there a way to do this… Thanks.

Comment: What are you saying couldn't be true. Do you mean abstract class? Anyway, please provide [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following in your `OnModelCreating`:

```
modelBuilder.Ignore<YourInterface>();
```